# Copy and paste (special) of the content of "equation" in WORD to dreamweaver

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, dreamweaver

An ordinary piece of text (even formatted) in WORD can be copied to dreamweaver without any problem. But those written via "equation" will be totally ignored.

What I have done is to double click that content to convert it back to normal text before I do the copy and paste (special).

Is there any other way?

Comment: Related [1](https://superuser.com/q/1071068/152004), [2](https://superuser.com/q/1295470/152004), ...

Comment: @Rubén Thanka for giving a right direction. In that post, I have added the following comment "I don't have a MathType tab on my WORD. I am wondering if I install one, will it be part of my WORD as an icon on the ribbon?"